# wkhtmltopdf is randomly adding extra padding to last row

Tags: html, css, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to make a PDF of QR codes, but wkhtmltopdf is adding random padding on the last row of the page even though it should fit fine. It renders fine in the browser.

Full code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/pxga201s/2/

The command I use to render it is:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0 --margin-top 0 'file:///path/to/qrcodes-5-6.pdf.html' '/path/to/qrcodes-5-6.pdf'
```

I am using `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)` on Mac 10.10.5.

[image]
When I use:

```
tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid; 
    page-break-after: auto;
}
```

it still adds the padding, but just pushes it to the next page:

[image]

Comment: You gave the image a height of 72mm and the page to print is 297mm, which will give 4.125 rows, which make the last row not fit. In addition there is the text. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you'll always have 4 `<tr>` in table you could just do `page-break-after: always;` on `<table>` without page break on `<tr>` elements.

And if you'll have all in one table then you could do something like this (without page break on `<table>`):

```
tr:nth-child(4n+5){
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

I tested both and it works fine. Even with much more pages.

**Update**

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/pxga201s/4/

Comment: Have you got an example, because when I try it, it still adds the random extra padding.

Comment: There is not much to see because it's just change in css like I described. I added jsfiddle so you can see it. I am also using 0.12.3 version but on Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding `page-break-inside: avoid;` to all table elements in the scss template fixed an issue I was having!